# HDMI Screen interference and intermittant blinking

Tags: hdmi

OK, Befote I describe this issue. Here's the setup..
RPi3B+ with external USB HD boot, The PSU is a TracoPower (professional) 5A PSU. The RPi power LED is not blinking nor lightening symbol on screen. HDMI_BOOST=4, HDMI local monitor, keyboard and mouse. VNC connection used occasionally

In 'normal' operation the HDMI screen is solid stable with no interference. 
and has been running its tasks 24/7 for over a month in this manner.

Right, the issue

When I am also connected remotely by VNC, interference lines appear across the HDMI monitor screen, but not the VNC screen and HDMI screen occasionally blanks for a few seconds, but not the VNC screen. All tasks are still running correctly. The only visual indication is the interference and blanking of the HDMI screen

Ideas? thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the GPU can't work fast enough for both display and VNC capture.
To help this poor GPU, we can reduce the display framerate by adding :

> dispmanx_offline=1

to the file `/boot/config.txt` and reboot. This will enable the double-buffering method.

There will be less refresh rate on your screen, but every frame should be correct.

Edit : you can also try another memory split, giving more memory to the GPU and less for the RAM.
Add or edit :

> gpu_mem=128

in your `/boot/config.txt` file.